# getAsFile returning null in onPaste event when copying embedded image from outlook

Tags: javascript, html, outlook, drag-and-drop, copy-paste

My client frequently receives emails in Outlook with screenshots embedded into the text.  I'm building them a work order tracker website, and they want to copy/paste from the email into the web page I'm building. (They are using Chrome Version `79.0.3945.117 (Official Build) (64-bit)` and Microsoft Office 365 ProPlus Outlook Version `1902 (Build 11328.20492 Click-to-Run))`

When they select the entire email's content the data in `e.clipboardData.items` doesn't include any references to the image.  It only includes the text (in plain, rte, and html formats) and the files collection has a length of 0.

When they select a single image in Outlook and copy/paste it into my form the data in `e.clipboardData.items` includes rte, html, and file types. The files collection still has a length of 0 though.  When I try to call `getAsFile()` on the item with the kind of file (and type of image/png) it returns `null`.

If the client right clicks the image and saves it, they can then upload it to my `input type=file` control, but I'm trying to save them some effort as they do this multiple times every day.

I've got a text box with an `onpaste` event:

```html
<textarea name="maincontent_0$txtDetails" rows="2" cols="20" id="maincontent_0_txtDetails" class="orderFormDetails" onpaste="onPaste(event)"></textarea>
```

and a file input control:

```html
<input type="file" name="maincontent_0$fuNewAttachment" id="maincontent_0_fuNewAttachment">
```

The `onpaste` event is defined as the following:

```js
        function onPaste(e)
        {
            var items = e.clipboardData.items;

            const dT = new ClipboardEvent('').clipboardData || // Firefox < 62 workaround exploiting https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1422655
                       new DataTransfer();

            for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
            {
                if (items[i].kind == "file")
                {
                    var blob = items[i].getAsFile();
                    if (blob != null)
                    {
                        dT.items.add(blob);
                    }
                }
            }
            if (dT.items.length > 0)
            {
                var uploadField = document.getElementById("maincontent_0_fuNewAttachment");
                uploadField.files = dT.files;
            }
        }
```

If I grab the html data instead of the file data I can get the location on the user's hard drive where the image is cached, but that's useless to me as I can't get the actual file's contents.

I've also tried using drag/drop to upload the image from Outlook and run into a similar problem (the `e.dataTransfer.files` collection is empty and the `e.dataTransfer.items` collection only has html with a local url to the image, not it's contents.)

Is there anything I can do to get at the contents of the image or is Outlook just not sending it?

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a while ago, but I just wanted to give my two cents. (I am writing here as an 'answer' too because I don't have enough credits to add a 'comment'... so sorry about that!)

I had the **exact** problem that Brian Heward had. The answer that muditgoel3011 gave was 100% accurate. Essentially, when you copy multiple images onto your clipboard, it reads as a RTF instead. Thus, you have to isolate the item in your event.clipboardData that is type 'text/rtf'.

Then you can use the rtf.js (or another equivalent library that helps parse RTF) and convert all of the RTF data into buffers and append that to your HTML document (or another equivalent).

However, it only really worked on my Mac OS (and not on my Windows environment). It stems from the size of the rtf from the clipboard. Copy/pasting 2-3 images from Outlook would be less than 1MB on my Mac whereas it would be around ~60MB on Windows. A typical email would consist of around 30 images, and thus crashes my browser on Windows. On Mac, it works perfectly fine.

My example code is using Quill as an Editor:

```
for (let i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    if (items[i].type.indexOf('image') === 0) {
        image = items[i].getAsFile();
    }
    else if (items[i].type.indexOf('text/rtf') === 0) {
        var rtf = e.clipboardData.getData('text/rtf');
        var stringToBinaryArray = function(txt) {
            var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(txt.length);
            var bufferView = new Uint8Array(buffer);
            for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
                bufferView[i] = txt.charCodeAt(i);
            }
            return buffer;
        }
        
        var doc = new RTFJS.Document(stringToBinaryArray(rtf), {});
        
        let self = this;
        doc.render()
            .then(function(htmlElements) {
                const div = document.createElement("div");
                div.append(...htmlElements);
                let delta = self.quill.clipboard.convert(div.innerHTML)
                self.quill.setContents(delta, 'silent');
            })
            .catch(error => console.error(error))
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone. It definitely helped me. Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

When images etc are copied from outlook, they live in RTF format in the clipboard.  Majority of HTML editors such as Extjs editor, devxtreme HTML editor; even pasting such images to google mail; and even pasting in vsts do not support processing the Rich Text Format (RTF) , hence pasting images from outlook fails in all these cases.
(In general, copy and paste from Microsoft products to browser-based products doesn't work so well: Microsoft has all sorts of special characters in their content which you cannot see but which can mess with what you paste.
What you need is be able to transform the RTF content into HTML and paste. Algo is: Check if image file available in clipboarddata, if no; check if html content there, if yes; check whether that html content is refering to local file urls in img tags somewhere (ie, src="file:// exists in html content); if yes, check for rtf content, if exists; use a library like rtfjs and transform it to render to browser in paste handler.