# Upload image when user pastes an image through Mobile

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have built a feature where an image is uploaded by copy/pasting it on a textarea. It works correctly if I am using desktop, however, if I use phone to copy paste an image, I get this error:

```
Failed to execute 'createObjectURL' on 'URL': Overload resolution failed.
```

Why is this happening on phone, and what can I do to fix it?

Sandbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-driscoll-bds08v?file=/src/App.js

Output on Desktop (I pasted it 3 times):

[image]

Output on Phone:

[image]

Comment: Try to change `item.type.indexOf("image") !== -1` to `/^image\//.test(item.type)`. I try in my Android and I found that there is `image-uri` type, I'm not sure what it is but its return `null` when called `getAsFile`.

Comment: And this also might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59758501/getasfile-returning-null-in-onpaste-event-when-copying-embedded-image-from-outlo